# Dump of Nearline Bucket Object Details

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How could I dump the output of gsutils ls -L gs://BUCKET/** to disk? And what would be the likely cost of this?

1. The bucket in question is about 100GB over ~200K objects.
2. Am I correct in assuming that the -L returns 1000 objects per call and that those calls are class A billed at $0.10 per 10K?
3. So (200000/1000) * 0.10 would be $20 for the whole bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. About dumping the output of your gsutil list command, if you are running the Command from the Cloud Shell on your GCP Console, you can actually export the Output data by following the steps described in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/uploading-and-downloading-files#uploading_and_downloading_files) And there is really [no costs associated with using the Cloudshell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/pricing). Charges may apply for read operations for each of the gsutil list command executed to the GCS, however. You can determine estimates of such charges by using the [GCP Calculator] (https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)
2. The -L flag when used with the "gsutil ls" command is not used to specify 1000 objects per call. As explained in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls#listing-object-details), the flag only allows gsutil to output additional information about your GCS Objects.

As explained in [this Stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551171/limit-on-files-returned#answer-12552896), gsutil ls command usually return about 1000 results for each underlying GETs and iterates through subsequent results.

[This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class) has all the information on the types of operations available in GCS. Get operations fall under Class A or Class B operation classification, depending on the API used. By default, [gsutil commands use the JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil#syntax), hence, if you run your commands with the default config, then those operations would be Class A operations.

3. Again, for estimates on your GCP/GCS charges, please use the GCP Calculator. And take note, that the output of such calculations are just estimates. There might be some variances when you get the actual billing cost.